# Exclude Subfolders from Rewrite rule htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a blog page on my website and .htaccess is as below to convert SEO Friendly URL

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail?prmn=$1 [L]
```

So, my URL becomes `http://example.com/title-of-blog` and it is working pretty fine and awesome but my client reported today that admin section is not working properly and i checked and found that URL `http://example.com/admin` is getting converted to `http://example.com/admin?prmn=admin` because of above rule.

I googled how to exclude `admin` folder from Rewrite then i got below

```
RewriteRule ^admin($|/) - [L]
```

When i use this then when i type `http://example.com/admin` then m getting error page that i defined in htaccess.

Please help. My Full Htaccess is as below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

 # remove .php from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L] 

# restrict .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /[^\ ]+\.php($|\ )
RewriteRule \.php$ / [F,L]

# remove .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail?prmn=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error-page
ErrorDocument 403 /error-page
ErrorDocument 500 /error-page
```

Comment: What if you change the order of the statements in your configuration files?

Comment: Can you show full .htaccess in question

Comment: my Htaccess has order as RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^admin($|/) - [L] RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail?prmn=$1 [L] .. So how u want to the chnage the order

Comment: @ Anubhava,, added htaccess in question

Comment: No Anubhava... admin  do not have .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there is an other rule that does something with `/admin`, but because you are using that second rule it will never reach that rule. Use a condition to exclude anything starting with admin instead. Also please note that the rule would rewrite it to `/blogdetail?prmn=admin`, so somewhere something is rewritten more.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|blogdetail)
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail?prmn=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This rule is giving 500 Error on my blog page now .. i.e. on `http://example.com/blog`

Comment: Hrmm; that's because it never worked in the first place. `/blogdetail` matches the rule, so it will match over and over and over again. I have edited the answer.

Comment: here now m facing one new challenge.. if i m having more then one rewrite rule same as `blogdetail` then do i need to include like this `!^/(admin|blogdetail|example1page)` but it dint work.. how to handle that then

Comment: If you mean that: `/page1` should go to `/blogdetail?prmn=..` and `/page2` should go to `/blah?asdf=..`, think about this: how does apache know when to rewrite to `/blogdetail` and when to rewrite to `/blah`. It doesn't. Make sure that each rule has a common prefix (e.g. `/blog/page1` and `/news/page2`). Then your content is organized well, and it is easy to make the rules for them.

Comment: I didnt get your common prefix example. Can u pl elaborate ?

Comment: I think it would be better if you ask a new question then.

Comment: @ Sumurai8 here is the new question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174865/rewrite-rule-htaccess-disturbing-other-rewrite-rules`

Comment: @Gags I hope Jon Lin's answer clears up any confusion.

Comment: I would recommend logging mod_rewrite while you debug what is going on. It should give you an idea which rules conflict, or what line is giving a syntax error.

Comment: How to enable that please. i m new to htaccess

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging Remember that it needs to be put in httpd.conf, and that you need to restart Apache.