# Rewrite rule htaccess disturbing other rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a page on my website that is getting generated dynamically to list all outlets based on `cityf` parameter and below is rewrite rule to convert it into SEO friendly URL and it is working pretty well.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /cityres?cityf=$1 [L]
```

I have a blog page on my website and .htaccess is as below to convert SEO Friendly URL (`http://example.com/title-of-blog`)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail?prmn=$1 [L]
```

Now the problem here i am facing that when someone visits `blog` page then the link `http://example.com/title-of-blog` instead of displaying blog detail on the page, displays my Error message that `No outlets near title-of-blog`.

I got the issue that Apache is not able to identify when to rewrite `cityres` page and when to rewrite `blogdetail` page.

Someone suggested that `Make sure that each rule has a common prefix (e.g. /blog/page1 and /news/page2).` but i did not get that.

Any suggestions here please?

---

EDIT:
Whole htaccess is as below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# remove .php from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L] 

# remove .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

ErrorDocument 404 /error-page
ErrorDocument 403 /error-page 

RewriteRule ^food-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /pdetail?res_id=$1&location=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^foodies-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ /pdetail_new?res_id=$1&location=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /pdetail_ne?location=$1&res_id=$2&name=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail_fm?prmn=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !cityres
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /cityres?cityf=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your rules match the exact same pattern. Therefore, the first rule will always match and the second rule does nothing.

Looking at the first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail?prmn=$1 [L]
```

This matches `http://example.com/title-of-blog` as well as `http://example.com/city-name`

When you look at it, you can tell which needs to be handled by blogdetail and which needs to be handled by cityres, but the regex `([^/.]+)` sees them both as exactly the same, and matches both. Your regex doesn't know the difference, so whatever the first rule is, both URL's will get matched by it.

Like you said, someone suggested using a prefix. That way, the regex *knows* which is which:

```
RewriteRule ^city/([^/.]+)/?$ /cityres?cityf=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail?prmn=$1 [L]
```

ANd your URLs will look like:

```
http://example.com/city/city-name
http://example.com/blog/title-of-blog
```

If you're really hung up about not adding prefixes, you can remove the second prefix:

```
RewriteRule ^city/([^/.]+)/?$ /cityres?cityf=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail?prmn=$1 [L]
```

So that you have:

```
http://example.com/city/city-name
http://example.com/title-of-blog
```

---

EDIT:

Your 500 server error is caused by the rules looping. You need to add a condition so that they won't keep matching:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail?prmn=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !cityres
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /cityres?cityf=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Good detailed answer +1 and congrats for 100K :)

Comment: @JonLin .. I tried as `RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail_fm.php?prmn=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /cityres?cityf=$1 [L]` but now u i am getting 500 error on blog page :(

Comment: Now my Htaccess look like `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /cityres?cityf=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)/?$ /blogdetail_fm?prmn=$1 [L]` but still no luck.

Comment: @JonLin .. i added my full htaccess in question as i m still facing 500

Comment: @Gags when I setup cityres.php and blogdetail_fm.php files, those rules work fine for me. What does your error logs say?

Comment: @JonLin .. nt able to trace error log on cpanel..  r u seeing any conflicting errror in my htaccess

Comment: @JonLin .. not working for me.. not sure why :( ... have to check on local then

Comment: error in error.log says :: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.